# mongodb number of connections

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

I'm trying to get the number of connected clients to my mongo server. I want to know how many connections are established and who did open those connections.
I have tried doing so with `db.server status().connections` but it gives me a strange number. So I checked the exact clients with `db.currentOp(true)` and I have found out that from my own computer I'm using 8 connections on different ports. There are also some undefined clients (the client field is empty) and one with `0.0.0.0`.

Can anyone please explain to me this weird results and how can I get the number of open connections and the users themselves?

Comment: The connections count covers connections not only client connections but connections between MongoDB processes as well.

Comment: Many MongoDB drivers use [connection pooling](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/), which means that they open multiple parallel connections to the server.